# PHP PDO Firebird inserting

Tags: php, insert, pdo, firebird, auto-increment

I'm new in Firebird but I'd like to write a small script in PHP that reads a CSV file and fills an existing Firebird db with its data.
The problem is I don't really know how to use the autoincrement generator. I've googled a lot but it's still a mistery for me. There is a gen_main generator defined in the db and I can use it in the IBExpert's query builder but cannot in PHP...
I saw a function named ibase_gen_id, what is the "PDO-way" of it?
What is the process of inserting a row that has an autoincremented field with PDO?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the database using a trigger to autoincrement itself? Then you don't need to use it yourself

Comment: As I saw the table's dependencies in the IBExpert, there is no trigger dependence. Can I check it somehow to be sure? For example by adding a new record but leave blank the ID field?

Comment: Just issue an insert without the ID field and see what happens.

Comment: It says: "The insert failed because a column definition includes validation constraints. Validation error for column Id, value *** null ***"

Comment: Ok, then there is no trigger.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no trigger. :( So, what's next? In the DB there is a gen_main generator and as I see the values of ID fields it is used in multiple tables. I know it's not important, but I think it's strange...

Comment: Can I just select the next upcoming ID and use it for the insertion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: I have never used PDO, so I can't comment on PDO specifics.

Depending on your exact needs you can use: [NEXT VALUE FOR](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-conditional-nxtvlufor)

```
NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence-name>
```

or [GEN_ID](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-gen-id)

```
GEN_ID(<sequence-name>, 1)
```

To get the next value of the sequence/generator.

You can either use these directly in your INSERT statement, or first issue a SELECT query against RDB$DATABASE to retrieve the value yourself before inserting: in Firebird you need to use a SELECT to retrieve values, and you always need to select against a table. RDB$DATABASE is guaranteed to contain only one row (like Oracle's DUAL).
So you need `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_MAIN FROM RDB$DATABASE` or `SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_MAIN, 1) FROM RDB$DATABASE` to get the next sequence value.

In general however I would advise you to add a trigger to do the auto-increment for you, see [Firebird Generator Guide](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/generatorguide/firebird-generator-guide.html) for details. You can then use `INSERT ... RETURNING <column-list>` to retrieve the generated id.

Comment: Thank you, it was useful but I can't select the next value (query: "NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_MAIN"): "Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 1 NEXT"

Comment: That is why I noted to select against RDB$DATABASE: in Firebird you need to use a SELECT to retrieve values, and you always need to select against a table. RDB$DATABASE is guaranteed to contain only one row (like Oracle's DUAL). So you need `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_MAIN FROM RDB$DATABASE` or `SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_MAIN, 1) FROM RDB$DATABASE` to get the next generator value.

Comment: I can use a trick to retrieve the next value, but this is not a solution i think: select first 1 gen_id(GEN_MAIN,1) from "Product"

Comment: Use RDB$DATABASE, not a random table.

Comment: Ok, thanks! It works but i don't feel it's the proper way to get the next Id. But I underline, it works! It's not my DB I cannot add trigger or any modification except filling with data.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the next Id separately it is the only way. You could also consider doing something like `INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(ID, ...) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_MAIN, ...) RETURNING ID`